# How to terminate while loop once response is correct?

Tags: java, string, while-loop, user-input

I'm working on this program that says "get some ice cream"/"put on a jacket" if you type "hot/cold". However, even after you type in hot/cold, the program keeps going in the while loop. How can I make this program keep asking the user for their condition until they correctly respond with one of the two answers, and prevent it from continuously asking for a response even after the user types a correct answer?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class IfStatement {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean run = true;

        while(run) {

        System.out.println("What is your condition: ");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String x = input.nextLine();

        if(x.equals("hot"))
            System.out.println("Get some ice cream");

        else if(x.equals("cold"))
            System.out.println("Put on a jacket");

        else
            System.out.print("Try again, what is your condition: ");
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

your loop iterates as long as `run` is `true`. what you need to do is therefore to set `run` to be `false` once the input is correct. like this

```
if(x.equals("hot")){
   System.out.println("Get some ice cream");
   run = false;  // setting run to false to break the loop
}    

else if(x.equals("cold")) {
   System.out.println("Put on a jacket");
   run = false; // setting run to false to break the loop
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`break` statement can be used as well.

Answer (score 0):

You may also use **do while loop**.

In this case, you would have the ability to check your condition against "x" when the loop ends, and hence would not need additional flag.

However, do while loop will run at least once, which I assume you need as per your requirement.